# What is a dissipative system?

Tags: calculus, dynamical-systems

If one had a system:

\begin{align}
\dot{x} = f(x,y,z)\\
\dot{y} = g(x,y,z)\\
\dot{z}=h(x,y,z)
\end{align}
Where each function may have parameters. How would one know if the system is dissipative?

---

I believe fundamental to defining a dissipative system is the Lyapunov function. This function seems have non equilibrium solutions crossing lower and lower level sets of the Lyapunov function. Is this correct?

Comment: Do the systems define a conservative vector field? http://mathinsight.org/conservative_vector_field_determine

Comment: @Bey You want me to consider ${\bf{F}}= \left(f(x,y,z),g(x,y,z),h(x,y,z)\begin{matrix}& \\& \end{matrix}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\right)$ and then check if that is a conservative vector field? Is it normal to take ${\bf{F}}=(\dot{x},\dot{y},\dot{z})$?

Comment: I think i am thinking of a non-conservative field, not a dissipative one. Disregard.

Comment: No problem @Bey

Answer (score 1):

There are several notions of a dissipative system, one being the existence of a Lyapunov function with some appropriate properties (that may also vary).

Because of this, but also because you don't say anything else about the particular right-hand side, it is really to much to ask "How would one know if the system is dissipative?". In fact, it is complicated in general even if the right-hand side is known explicitly.

On the other hand, the description that you give in your last paragraph is fair.